# A more swifty way to check for nil

Tags: swift

My code needs to check if a scrollview is nil, and if it is populate it from the the view hierarchy.

```swift
var scrollview = scrollview
if scrollview == nil {
    scrollview = view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as? UIScrollView
}
```

This doesn't seem a very swifty way of doing this. I could use a `guard` statement but this also does not seem satisfying. What is a nice readable way of doing this within a function?

Comment: `filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first` => `first(where:)` is better because it will stop after first match instead of iterating all over and returning only the first one: `var scrollView = scrollView ?? view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView })` should do the trick.

Comment: If you were going to do it that way, there'd be no reason for the conditional cast. `view.subviews.first { $0 is UIScrollView } .map { $0 as! UIScrollView }`

Comment: @Jessy it returns optional type anyway. I prefer as? T and it is shorter

Comment: Like I said in my response to your comment on my answer, I wouldn't actually use a combination of both is and as. as is a functionality superset. I'm just saying that here, it is 100% verifiable that you have a non-optional instance with the map closure. Optionality is incorrect here—not demonstrative of known truth.

Comment: @Jessy Why in `view.subviews.first { $0 is UIScrollView } .map { $0 as! UIScrollView }` use `map{}`? Why not just `view.subviews.first { $0 is UIScrollView }  as! UIScrollView` then?

Comment: If it is known that a `UIScrollView` subview exists, `as! UIScrollView` is a more informative choice, and will allow the `scrollView` to not be `Optional`. Otherwise, that code can crash.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let scrollview = scrollview ?? view.subviews.first()
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }

  /// The first element of a given type.
  func first<T>(_: T.Type = T.self) -> T? {
    lazy.compactMap { $0 as? T } .first
  }
}
```

Comment: Does lazy avoid iterating all subviews? isn't it better to use `first(where:)` method and provide an early exit `first { $0 is T } as? T`?

Comment: `lazy`, which does what you say, normally isn't important for this use case, because `subviews` shouldn't be too large, but it might be. My issue with using both `is` and `as` is redundancy. If an element `is` an instance of a type, then obviously it can be cast to it. Only the `as?` is necessary. This is the cleanest form I've come up with.

Comment: But your method is not restricted to subviews. It is an instance method of Sequence.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? My implementation for `[UIView]` would look exactly the same except for the generic placeholder.

Comment: I meant it can be used for any type of element. If you are assuming it will always have just a few elements it is better to restrict the element type

Comment: @LeoDabus after some tests in the playground, what actually makes the `compactMap` not to iterate all the sequence elements is the iterator trick. (in conjunction with the `lazy`) That's very interesting.